# How to insert a text on specific part of a concatenated variable on fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I was creating a JavaScript function to dynamically create a table base on a JSON response from server. So far it's working just fine. But now I have to insert a class in my `<tr>` element but the condition was in the `<td>` loop..

**For example:**

```
//loop for tr
var tr='';
for(var x=0; x<100; x++)
{
  tr .="<tr>";
    //loop for td
    var td = '';

    for(var y = 0; y<10; y++)
     {
     //condition to add class on the parent tr
     if(y==3){ // should add class to tr }
       td += '<td>'+y+'</td>';
     }
 tr+=td+'</tr>';
}
```

The code above should generate a table with 100 rows with 10 columns. My problem is, is there a way to add a text to its parent node? If the condition is inside the child loop.

Expected result above is

```
<tr class='someclass'>
   <td>0</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>6</td>
   <td>7</td>
   <td>8</td>
   <td>9</td>
</tr> x100
```

Comment: What is the actual logic creating the `td` elements? I ask as `y` will always be `3` in one iteration of your current logic, so the `if` statement is redundant - just add the class to the `tr` when you create it.

Comment: Your logic looks flawed, you are saying for every third column (y) add class to row, should this be that every third row(x) add class?

Comment: So are you needing to add the `someclass` class if the length of your list is greater than or equal to `3` ?

Comment: ahh yes its just an example though.. coz on my actual json files, conditions are inside the td loop and is not always present. so the representation above is how could I posibly do it in that way. even if its always present base on that example

Comment: do you think its possible?

Comment: You could use a seperate string var to hold your row, building it with class="yourClass" then in your column appending, do your logic to check if the row should have the class, if not, replace it in your string with .replace() then append that string variable to your table building string. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: ahh okay yeah that might work.. I'll give it a try @RyanWilson Thanks!

Comment: @melvnberd No problem, I was going to place an example of what I mean in the answer box below, one minute.

Comment: @melvnberd Posted suggested answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a seperate variable to build your row on each iteration always adding the class to your row, then in the column adding, if you shouldn't have class, use string.replace() to replace your class attribute text with empty string, then append that to your table building string:

```
//loop for tr
var tr='';
for(var x=0; x<100; x++)
{
    let tempRowString = '<tr class="yourClass">';
    //loop for td
    var td = '';

    for(var y = 0; y<10; y++)
    {
       //condition to not add class on the parent tr
       if(!conditionMet){
           tempRowString = tempRowString.replace('class="yourClass"', '');
       }
    }

    tempRowString +=td+'</tr>';
    //Append your row string to your table building string
    tr += tempRowString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of `N` items and `.reduce` that Array into an Array of Array of a certain `length` i.e

```js
let arr = new Array(50)
let newArr = []
let splitArrayInto = 10

for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
  newArr.push(i)
}

let modifiedArr = newArr.reduce((pre, curr, i, orig) => {
  if(!(i%10)) {
    pre.push(orig.slice(i, i+splitArrayInto))
  }
            
  return pre
}, [])


console.log(modifiedArr)

const GENERATE_STRUCTURE = arr => arr.map(row => `<row class="yourClass">${GENERATE_DATA(row)}</row>`).join('')

const GENERATE_DATA = arr => arr.map(i => `<td>${i}</td>`).join('')

const TMPL = `${GENERATE_STRUCTURE(modifiedArr)}`

console.log(TMPL)
```

Now you have an array that resembles a `tr > td` layout where each new array is a `tr` and each item within that array is a `td`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @francis Leigh. I already made it working though

Comment: @melvnberd No problem, glad you got your solution. I have ammended my code to spit out the template as well just in case you were interested in another approach. It was a nice brain workout for me anyway :-)